# Using drop [R] selectively - only remove specified length-1 dimensions

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, subset

The `drop` function and the `drop` argument in the `[` subsetting function both work completely or not at all.  If I have, for example, a four-dimensional array whose 2nd and 4th dimensions are length 1 only, then `drop` will return a 2-dimensional array with both these dimensions removed.  How can I drop the 4th dimension but not the 2nd?

e.g.

```
arr <- array(1:4, c(2, 1, 2, 1))
drop(arr)
arr[,,, 1, drop = TRUE]
```

The reason for doing this in my case is so that I can set up the array correctly for binding to other arrays in `abind`.  In the example given, one might wish to bind `arr[,,, 1]` to a 3-dimensional array along dimension 2.

Answer (score 5):

I've thought about it some more and come up with a solution.  The below function defines the new target dimensions and fits the data into a new array of those dimensions.  `omit` is a vector of dimension numbers never to drop.

```
library("abind")
drop.sel <- function(x, omit){
  ds <- dim(x)
  dv <- ds == 1 & !(seq_along(ds) %in% omit)
  adrop(x, dv)
}
```

If anyone thinks they have a more elegant solution, I'd be happy to see it.

Comment: Additionally, I've just seen the `adrop` function in the `abind` package.  That seems to be designed for this.

Comment: Edited to incorporate `adrop`, in case anyone's watching!  This question was a lonely experience....  Someone obviously liked it though.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question well, but another way to do it is to just create a new array, using the old array as data, and specifying whatever dimensions you choose. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53554390/8436923

Comment: Also check the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654316/dont-drop-dimensions-when-subseting-3-dimensional-array

Comment: Good idea.  Do you know if either is more memory efficient, in the case of a big array?  I suspect it might be similar.  On a similar theme, I generally avoid using the `abind` function, preferring just to use `c` and then redefine the dimensions (if binding on the highest dimension).

Comment: I don't know whether there's a difference in memory-efficiency; sorry.