# Don't drop dimensions when subseting 3-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, r

Let `A` be a `1 x 2 x 2`-array:

```
> A <- array(0, dim=c(1,2,2))
> A
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
```

Then `A[,,1]` is dimensionless:

```
> A[,,1]
[1] 0 0
```

I would like to have:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
```

The `drop` argument does not yield what I want:

```
> A[,,1,drop=FALSE]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
```

I find that annoying. And buggy, because R identifies vectors to column matrices, not to row matrices.

Of course I could do `matrix(A[,,1], 1, 2)`. Is there a more convenient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just assign the `dim` based on the `MARGIN` we are extracting

```
`dim<-`(A[, ,1], apply(A, 3, dim)[,1])
 #     [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    0    0
```

Using another example

```
B <- array(0, dim = c(2, 1, 2))
`dim<-`(B[, ,1], apply(B, 3, dim)[,1])
 #    [,1]
#[1,]    0
#[2,]    0
```

---

If we are using a package solution, then `adrop` from `abind` could get the expected output

```
library(abind)
adrop(A[,,1,drop=FALSE], drop = 3)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0

adrop(B[,,1,drop=FALSE], drop = 3)
#     [,1]
#[1,]    0
#[2,]    0
```

Comment: Not cool but it looks like there's no better possible answer, so I accept. Thanks. FYI take a look at my answer, the `keep` package.

Answer (score 1):

```
t(A[,,1])
 [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
```

I though of it from your comment that R identifies vector to column matrix. I think transpose it gives what you want, and is a bit more convenient.

Comment: Yes, but if `A` is `2 x 1 x n`, I expect `A[,,1]` to be `2 x 1`, and this way will give `1 x 2`. I would like a solution which gives the expectation for both cases.

Comment: Well in these cases you can `t(t(A[,,1]))` . but indeed it is not that good because it depends on the case.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way around this. With `drop = TRUE`, any dimension of `1` gets dropped. You can see this if you look at the source for `ArraySubset` from [src/main/subset.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/subset.c#L412). At the end of the function we see this:

```
if (drop)
    DropDims(result);
```

The `DropDims` function is defined in [src/main/array.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/array.c#L288). In that function, we see

```
n = 0;
for (i = 0; i < ndims; i++)
    if (dim[i] != 1) n++;
```

and elsewhere in the function we see that dimensions of size one get ignored.

It's annoying that R determines the drop behavior from the result. It would be more natural if R only dropped indexed dimensions of length one, so that behavior would be as you expected in this example.

All that being, said, the following is ugly, bug it may work for your use case:

```
`dim<-`(A[,,1], dim(A)[-3])
 #>      [,1] [,2]
 #> [1,]    0    0
```

This doesn't generalize very well, but it works if you index by a single coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Another package solution: the `keep` package.

```
> library(keep)
> A <- karray(0, dim=c(1,2,2))
> A[,,1]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
attr(,"class")
[1] "keep"    "numeric"
```